# ADT Plug-in for Eclipse, cannot create Android Test Project

Tags: android, eclipse, plugins

I have installed (also uninstalled and re-installed) the most recent versions of Eclipse and the Android plug-in, but to no avail.  I cannot create a test project from an existing project...  I am attempting to follow the "Activity Testing" tutorial from developer.android.com.  Like the rest of the tutorials, the steps are basic and well documented, however I am stuck under "Creating the Test Case Class" :: "Adding the test case class file" between steps 3 & 4.  For the sake of specifics:

I select my active Android project, then click "New" -> "Project...".  In the wizard I select "Android" -> "Android Test Project" -> "Next".  I name it, choose "... existing source", define my local source directory, and click "Next".  Here is where we reach my problem:

[image]

This "Next" button does not respond.  You can see the button is active, regardless when clicked the wizard still will not proceed from this step.  Therefor I cannot create an Android Test Project from an existing project in Eclipse.  Any ideas?

Comment: No idea. Can you create a test project alongside creating a new projecT?

Comment: Yes, I can create a test project simultaneously with a regular Android Project. Weird, I know; but I need help.

Comment: Weird, the screenshot should reach the last step of wizard, where the Next button should be greyed out and Finish button should be active and gain focus. Try click Finis button to see if anything interesting happen.

Comment: @yorkw The Finish button doesn't respond either...

Comment: @JasonRobinson Glad other people have this problem so we might find the answer to fixing it. But no, I haven't solved this one.  I worked around it by creating a new project and test project at the same time then I cut & paste my existing code.

Comment: @Sam My problem seemed to be isolated, as I canceled the prompt and tried again, then it worked. One thing I noticed when it wasn't working that inbetween the first wizard screen and the screen you see should be a step that asks you which project you want to test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never learned why this wizard skipped a setup step and prevented me from building an Android Test Project from an existing project.  Since then, an IDE update was released and my build environment now behaves as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple, just dont click in the create from existing source, instead click create new project, and then next, and then click an existing android project

Comment: There was one catch: I never saw this screen, Eclipse skipped this step as Jason informed me.